# Python matrix indexing

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, indexing

I have the following code

```
l = len(time)     #time is a 300 element list
ll = len(sample)  #sample has 3 sublists each with 300 elements

w, h = ll, l 
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

for n in range(0,l):

    for m in range(0,ll):

        x=sample[m]
        Matrix[m][n]= x
```

When I run the code to fill the matrix I get an error message saying "list index out of range" I put in a print statement to see where the error happens and when m=0 and n=3 the matrix goes out of index.

from what I understand on the fourth line of the code I initialize a 3X300 matrix so why does it go out of index at 0X3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `Matrix[m][n]= x` to `Matrix[n][m]= x`

Answer (score 2):

The indexing of nested lists happens from the outside in. So for your code, you'll probably want:

```
Matrix[n][m] = x
```

If you prefer the other order, you can build the matrix differently (swap `w` and `h` in the list comprehensions).

Note that if you're going to be doing mathematical operations with this matrix, you may want to be using `numpy` arrays instead of Python lists. They're almost certainly going to be much more efficient at doing math operations than anything you can write yourself in pure Python.

Answer (score 1):

Note that indexing in nested lists in Python happens from outside in, and so you'll have to change the order in which you index into your array, as follows:

```
Matrix[n][m] = x
```

For mathematical operations and matrix manipulations, using `numpy` two-dimensional arrays, is almost always a better choice. You can read more about them [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).